# Distribution of a binomial random variable multiplied by a constant

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to model a process in which a success is the generation of $2$ items.  If I model the process using a binomial random variable with p equal to the probability of success, I can compute the parameters for a binomial distribution.

For example, if I generate a $100000$ instances of a binomial random variable with $250000$ trials and probability of success $0.00065$:

```
s = rbinom(100000,250000,p2)
hist(s, breaks=30,freq=FALSE)
sapply(min(s):max(s), function(q) { 
  points(q,dbinom(q,250000,p2),pch=19)})
```

[image: Histogram of binomial random variable]

This gives the the number of successes, but I want to also model the number of observations which is $2$ times the number of successes.  I assumed I could multiple $p$ times $2$, but that clearly isn't right.  That translates to twice the probability of observing a success, and not the actual number of observations.

```
s2 = 2*s
hist(s2, breaks=30,freq=FALSE)
sapply(min(s2):max(s2), function(q) { 
  +   points(q,dbinom(q,250000,2*p2),pch=19)})
```

[image: Distribution of 2 times binomial random variable]

The mean is correct in that it has just shifted upward by a factor of $2$, but the variance is wrong.  Analytically, I would have expected the variance to be $4np(1-p)$, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y=X$, where $X$ is a binomial distribution. Notice that $Y=2X$ is not a binomial distribution.

In particular, $Y$ always take even numbers.

Its expected value is indeed $2np$ and its variance is $4np(1-p)$ but it does not follow  any binomial distribution.

Remark: From the first sentence, I am not sure if $2X$ is what you are interested, if a success is based on two pair of events with sucess probability $p$ independently and there are $n$ such pairs, then perhaps you are interested in $Bin(n, p^2)$.

Edit:

You use the $Bin(n, 2p)$ which has variance $n(2p)(1-2p)=2np-4np^2 < 4np-4np^2$

Comment: True, this is not a proper Binomial distribution.  Could it not be approximated by one, however, assuming the right parameters?  I would have expected my second plot to at least approximate the shape, but it appears that the variance is too small.

Comment: See the edit to show why is your variance smaller.

Comment: Regarding Bin(n,p^2), I think this is taken care of in the definition of a success in the original trials.  p is the probability that two events have occurred simultaneously already.  The probability of any single event would be sqrt(p), correct?

Comment: If the success probability of each sub event is $\sqrt{p}$. Sure. But yup, you shouldn't end up with $2p$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation regarding why the variance is smaller in my plots.  That is tremendously helpful!  Another option is to approximate it with a normal distribution.  If I use the mean = $2np$ and variance = $4np(1-p), I get what appears to be a good approximation.  The same problem holds that this is not really a normal distribution since only even values are present.

Comment: You could call this a *scaled binomial distribution*. If $X\sim\mathcal{Bino}(n,p)$ and $c>0$, then $cX$ is a scaled binomial. All probabiity calculations can be done via the binomial distribution of $X$.